# How to set multiple images in collection view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, ios9

I have a list of album images that i displayed in collection view.
The problem is when i select image from collection view i have to set another image on cell that is CheckMark.png image,which shows image selected check mark.
please help me to solve this.

I use this code to set image but it was not working.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     AlbumImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AlbumImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckMark.png"]];
 }
```

Comment: Your approach is not correct. Cells will be recycled and used again. You should set a flag or something on `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` and let the cell populate on `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` with your conditions. If the cell is visible when you want to change it, you should reload its content. All of which is explained well on the documents of course.

Answer (score 1):

In your data source add property bool type for each modal. Then make bool false/true at time of check click and reload data.

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to solve this task ,You need to  store boolean value **No** in an another array name as like **checkMarkArray** same as size of image array.Then you check the **checkMarkArray** boolean value ,if the boolean value is  true set image to the imageview in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` like this

```
 [cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckMark.png"]]
```

And in the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` change  **value of object at index** to boolean True  in the **checkMarkArray**.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to add BOOL in  **AlbumImageCell.h** same like below code...

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isCellSelected;
```

Then Update your code in both `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` both method as per your need

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     AlbumImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AlbumImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.isCellSelected) {
        //add chackmark image here
        [cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckMark.png"]];
    }else {
        //add unchak image here
        [cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UNCheckMark.png"]];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    AlbumImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AlbumImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.isCellSelected) {
        cell.isCellSelected = FALSE;
        //set unchacked image to cell
        [cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UNCheckMark.png"]];
    }else {
        cell.isCellSelected = TRUE;
        //set checked image to cell here like
        [cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckMark.png"]];
    }
}
```

*another way is store selected cell's indexpaths in array from didSelectItemAtIndexPath  and check in cellForItemAtIndexPath method. but Bool is very easy insted of this.*
Hope it helps you.